# loop 'for' for string of numbers

Tags: python

Note: you have input where have 5 numbers:

```
Sample Input: 12 21 15 19 8
Sample Output:   12 8

x = input()
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

need to use input() in program but loop takes the number 12 as 1 and 2. how to avoid this

```
input: 12
output: 1 2
```

Comment: When looping over a string you loop over 1 character at a time. You probably want to split on spaces. Use `input().split(" ")`

Comment: `input().split()` to split on arbitrary spacing, so it still works if you type two spaces between numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `split()` method separates a sentence into a list of words.

```
x = input().split()
for i in x:
    print(i)
```

[Python String split() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_split.asp)

Answer (score 0):

In case you also want to turn the numbers into integers to use in your code, you  can do:

```py
x = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

which just casts each of the numeric strings created by `split()` to `int` types and puts them back into a list.